# Shared Preferences available to all activites

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Please help.. I am stacked with my thesis.. 
Here I use Shared Preferences, which works well between 2 activities. However, I want to keep the data available for multiple activities. How do I do that?

The way that I save:

```
SharedPreferences example = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES_LOGIN, 0);
Editor editor = example.edit();
editor.putString("username", username.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

The way that I retrieve:

```
SharedPreferences example = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES_LOGIN, 0);
String userString = example.getString("username", "null");
tv.setText("Welcome " +userString);
```

How can I obtain this value from another activity and another activity, without having to save again and again this single value? 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are retrieving the `SharedPreferences` using the same name, then the same SharedPreferences instance (and all of the values that have been committed so far) is returned as per [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), whether it is from a new `Activity` or the one that created the shared preference key.